# How to configure Spring without persistence.xml?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, configuration

I'm trying to set up spring xml configuration without having to create a futher `persistence.xml`. But I'm constantly getting the following exception, even though I included the database properties in the `spring.xml`

```
    Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Users\me\workspace\app\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No persistence units parsed from {classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml}
```

spring.xml:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
  </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
     <property name="jpaProperties">
         <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
         </props>
      </property>
    </bean>
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Specify the "packagesToScan" & "persistenceUnitName" properties in the entityManagerFactory bean definition.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" >
            <list>
                <value>org.mypackage.*.model</value>
            </list>
        </property>

        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Note that this is for Spring version > 3.1

Comment: Do you know to configure Composite Persistent Unit and its members without persistence.xml file in the same way needed by you.

Comment: does it allow us to load the entityManager with spring like : ```@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;```

Comment: I get "No persistance provider specified in EntityManagerConfiguration..." exception. Did you miss it in your answer?

Comment: What is the use of line
<property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
, Where is 'myPersistenceUnit' is exists??

Comment: But this is a xml config!

Comment: @Zaki but for persistenceUnitName, don't we need to define it in persistence.xml?

Answer (score 41):

## From Spring Guide [Accessing Data with JPA](http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
public class Application {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(H2).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
        lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        lef.setPackagesToScan("hello");
        return lef;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter hibernateJpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(false);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        hibernateJpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.H2);
        return hibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
    }
```

## Spring Boot

With Spring Boot enabled application this is even easier:

**Sample `application.yaml`**

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:test
        username: sa
        password: sa
        driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
    jpa:
        database: H2
        show-sql: false
        hibernate:
            format_sql: true
            ddl-auto: auto
```

Comment: this solution works for me, except in the instructions above, setPackagesToScan("package name"), where "package name" is the package include your entity classes, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html for reference

Answer (score 4):

MariuszS' answer is good except that the `entityManagerFactory` method should return EntityManagerFactory. To do that it can be written like this:

```
@Bean
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter) {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("hello");
    return lef.object();
}
```

For future audience: below code worked:

```
@Bean (name = "entityManagerFactory")
public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource, JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter)
{
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean lef = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    lef.setDataSource(dataSource);
    lef.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
    lef.setPackagesToScan("*.models*");
    lef.afterPropertiesSet(); // It will initialize EntityManagerFactory object otherwise below will return null
    return lef.getObject();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a `PersistenceProvider` implementation (e.g. `org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider`), you can use the [PersistenceProvider#createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitInfo info, Map map)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceProvider.html#createContainerEntityManagerFactory-javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo-java.util.Map-) method to bootstrap an `EntityManagerFactory` without needing a `persistence.xml`.

However, it's annoying that you have to implement the `PersistenceUnitInfo` interface, so you are better off using Spring or Hibernate which both support bootstrapping JPA without a `persistence.xml` file.

```
this.nativeEntityManagerFactory = provider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(
    this.persistenceUnitInfo, 
    getJpaPropertyMap()
);
```

Where the [PersistenceUnitInfo](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/spi/PersistenceUnitInfo.html) is implemented by the Spring-specific [MutablePersistenceUnitInfo](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/persistenceunit/MutablePersistenceUnitInfo.html) class.