# Spring-JPA "Class is not entity"

Tags: java, spring, jpa, intellij-idea

I have an issue with my project using Spring (4.2.4 Release) and JPA (2.1)

To be brief the problem is in the part of code in file "*Book.java*":

```
@Table(name = "book")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Book.getBooks", query="select b from com.jpaProSpring.Book b ")
})
@Entity(name = "Book")
public class Book implements Serializable {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;

    public Book() {

    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column
    public String getTitle() {
        return this.title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Column
    public String getDescription() {
        return this.description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

and particulary in

> query = "select b from com.jpaProSpring.Book b" )

My IntelliJ  highlights the **Book** and says that class is not en entity. And I have no idea, why it is so given that I was doing an example from the book.

Link to my project https://github.com/yuraguz/LearnORM.git

My spring-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
       ">


        <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

       <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
              <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
              <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3310/testdb"/>
              <property name="username" value="root"/>
              <property name="password" value="1234"/>
              <property name="initialSize" value="5"/>
              <property name="maxActive" value="10"/>
       </bean>

       <bean id="transactionManager"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
              <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="emf" />
       </bean>

       <bean id="emf"
             class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
              <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
              <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
              </property>
              <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.jpaProSpring" />
              <property name="jpaProperties">
                  <props>
                      <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                      <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">3</prop>
                      <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size">50</prop>
                      <prop key="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">10</prop>
                      <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                  </props>
              </property>
       </bean>

         <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
         <context:annotation-config />
         <context:component-scan base-package="com.jpaProSpring" />
</beans>
```

P.S: I know entities must be declared in ***persistence.xml*** in ***META-INF/*** source. But if I understand correctly Spring4 make it possible to config project without persistance.xml. So, I don't use it.

Comment: Post the entire file for the class.

Comment: Does it run fine in your tests? Because IDEs try to help, but sometimes they aren't right, or they aren't configured correctly enough to give correct messages.

Comment: I guess this might be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381943/how-to-configure-spring-without-persistence-xml

Comment: @chrylis I've done it)

Comment: @JBNizet the fact is that i don't use tests for this project :)

Comment: @MatrixBuster There is a good information about my problem, but after doing those recomendations I've got another message from compiler: **No query defined for that name [Book.getBooks]** (and old problem persists)

Comment: Your entity is named `Book` not `com.jpaProSpring.Book`. Basically your query is using the wrong name of the entity.

Comment: I checked your code. It works fine. Is your problem just your IDE dose not recognize entities? Does your program runs properly at runtime?

Comment: @M.Deinum if i use name "Book" he even doesn't find the entity Book (IDE highlights this name **"Book"** and say, that he cannot resolve this type..) So, when y use this name **"com.jpaProSpring.Book"**, my IDE find this clas Book, but says that Book is not defined an entity

Comment: The fact that your IDE says that doesn't mean it is wrong (or that your IDE is right). Trust me the name is `Book` and nothing else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use InellyJ Idea, possible you didn't add JPA facet in your project. Try open menu *"File"->"Project Structure"*, then select in list of Project Settings section named *"Facets"*. Check if you have configured JPA facet in list of facets. If you don't see JPA facet, just add it (by pressing "+" button). Optionally, you can specify persistence.xml (if you have it) and Default JPA provider. Hope this will help.

Comment: Yes, it works!
Thank you all very much! It is an incredible feeling when everything works :) yeeeah

Comment: and what should we do in Eclipse and Spring Boot?