# Querydsl with jdbc - Maven configuration(querydsl plugin doesn't generate Q class)

Tags: java, maven, jdbc, querydsl

I want to use QueryDSL with JDBC (Not JPA). 
So in pom.xml I put these dependencies and plugin:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-sql</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
....
<plugins>
    <plugin>
          <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
          <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.7.4</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <goals>
                <goal>export</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>            
          </executions>
          <configuration>
            <jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/chebuoni</jdbc.url>
                <jdbc.driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driver>
            <jdbcUser>root</jdbcUser>
            <jdbcPassword>root</jdbcPassword>
            <packageName>it.group.myproject</packageName>
            <targetFolder>/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
          </configuration>
          <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
              <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
              <version>10.13.1.1</version>
            </dependency>
          </dependencies>
        </plugin> 

    </plugins>
```

Maven can do its building without errors only if I out **generic-export** as goal, but in this case it does not create the Q class I need in order to use QueryDSL.
I also have my class Person mapped with annotation @Entity in package it.group.myproject

********************** edit **********************
Following @Nikolas tips I was finally able to generate Q class, and I add in the pom this plugin:

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
              <jdbc.url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/myDB</jdbc.url>
              <jdbc.driver>com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver</jdbc.driver>
              <jdbc.user>root</jdbc.user>
              <jdbc.password>root</jdbc.password>
              <packageName>myPackage</packageName>
              <targetFolder>/target/generated-sources/java</targetFolder>
              <namePrefix>S</namePrefix>
                <imports>
                    <import>java.io</import>
                    <import>java.io.File</import>
                </imports>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
                <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
                <version>10.13.1.1</version>
              </dependency> 
            </dependencies>
          </plugin>
```

But still, there is the part of the entityManager that I don't know how to configure:

```
JPAQuery<?> queryFactory = new JPAQuery<Void>(entityManager);
```

I read this tutorial --> https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jpa/jpa-entitymanager-example/ in which it seems I need a persistence.xml file so that I can do this:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("jcg-JPA");
    EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
```

so I configured persistence and the entitymanager bean in this way:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="jcg-JPA" />
</bean>
```

And this is persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

```
    <persistence-unit name="jcg-JPA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8889/myDB" />
    </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

But server fails at startup:

```
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
GRAVE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata: method 
<init>()V not found at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findPersistenceMetadata(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:351)
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:295)
```

Comment: Btw as your original question (generatiing MetaData) was answered you might want to consider not to mix-in different problems but instead close this one and ask another, more specific question about your current challenge.

Comment: yeah...I'm sorry :) ... now I'm definitely stuck with the last error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to confuse some things here, JDBC and JPA are two different pair of shoes, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11881548/jpa-or-jdbc-how-are-they-different). You can not go without JPA here as it aids with the creation of the metamodel. You even refer to it yourself by using @Entity. You will use both JDBC and JPA.

That being said, your library is quite out of date. [They restructured their package structure some time ago.](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.querydsl/querydsl-jpa/4.1.4) I guess that this results in the NPE, as the maven plugin expects *com.querydsl* classes.

[This is the current Git project](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-jpa). Check the maven config on the .md, this one should work.

[This is the documentation to refer to](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.1.3/reference/html_single/).

(Edit)

**EntityManager via persistence.xml**

I know that "I don't want no Hibernate"-Feeling, at this point you might find a proper JPA-Implementation useful, though. You *could* implement JPA yourself, but ... don't do it, yet. Anyway, the *EntityManager* is JPA-Territory. If you don't like Hibernate, use EclipseLink. But chose one. Then, follow the tutorials on how to set up your *persistence.xml* (in which you specify the entity manager factory, introduce the persistent classes and configure the DB-Connection). Then you can refer to the factory by name as your tutorial mentioned. Configuring JPA is out of the scope of the QueryDSL-Tut, just chose a how-to the JPA-"Implementor" provides, they are quite decent.

**Spring**
Check [this post about setting up JPA the "Spring-Way"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381943/how-to-configure-spring-without-persistence-xml), maybe that is what you wanted. It still requires you to make a choice in regards to Hibernate, though. That is why I kinda left the paragraph above.

(Edit2)
Regarding your persistence.xml, I think you might need to name all your persistent classes ([Another link, another Tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.6/reference/en/html/configuration.html)) in your xml, at the moment you specified none, so the scanner does not find any. In Spring, you can specify "packages to scan", which basically does a similar job.